# Solution to a first-order rational difference equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, recurrence-relations, recursion

I am interested in the following first-order rational difference equation (recurrence relation):
$$x_{n+1} = x_n + \dfrac{\alpha}{x_n} + \beta \ ; \ x_0 >0$$
for positive $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Is there a general solution for this kind of difference equation? Or how can I approximate it?

It clearly is strictly increasing and a solution should be roughly linear for large n.
Since it is a rational difference equation I tried different substitutions like $x_n = \dfrac{p_n}{q_n}$ but could not come up with a system of difference equations that appears to be solveable.